# JavaFX, Intelli J and OSGI

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, osgi

I haven't seen any examples of Java FX, Intelli J and OSGI being used together. I know eclipse has e(fx)clipse to help with JavaFX's problems with OSGI but it doesn't seem like intellij has something similar.

Are JavaFX developers on intelli j using alternatives to OSGI or achieving the modularity that OSGI gives you in any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've released some Early Access versions of [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DromblerFX), a new Rich Client Platform for JavaFX based on OSGi (Apache Felix) and Maven.

You can read more about Drombler FX here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/search/label/Drombler

There's a [Getting Started](http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted) page which explains how to create, build and run a Drombler FX sample application with a few simple steps.